# In iOS, how can you programmatically fill out a pdf form field?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, core-graphics

I need to take an existing pdf file and programmatically fill in a list of form fields with text and then save the pdf without ever displaying it to the user.

For instance, if the pdf file contains fields named "LastName", and "FirstName" I would like to set the value of "FirstName" to "Louis" and then save the file.

I've been searching for a long time and can't find any guidance on even where to start since  the iOS documentation (and most of the questions on here) seem geared towards displaying or creating pdf content instead of modifying it.

**EDIT:**
My main question is:  Is it possible to open a pdf stream (I know how to do this) and copy each existing pdf dictionary item into a new pdf?   I have not been able to find a way to write the dictionary items to a pdf.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? Would you mind sharing what you came up with?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I haven't.  I've just left the form fields empty and written strings directly into the file....

Comment: @lnafziger Can you post some code on how you wrote the strings directly into the file? I've been working on this, but modifying the form value ruins any binary data in the file.

Comment: @lnafziger I'm assuming this is because the xref data becomes corrupted when I modify the data. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14292892/953105) Did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @paulrehkugler: Yeah, I gave up on the form and just added new text to the pdf.  If you ask a question about how to do that I'll be happy to add some code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that kind of functionality will ever be in the iOS frameworks. The reason most of the related info you can find "seem[s] geared towards displaying or creating pdf content instead of modifying it" is because that's what the vast majority of use cases will want or need for PDF functionality.

You'll need to find a 3rd party library that can open up PDFs, fill out the AcroForm fields, and then stamp out a PDF. I use iText on Java (there is also iTextSharp for C#) but I don't know of anything for Objective-C.

Once you find that library, you'll need to integrate it into your project. There are undoubtedly several related questions/answers here on SO for whatever version of the SDK you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I am not wanting a 3rd party library.  I want to use the iOS framework functions to write a generic solution (which I will share with others when I finish it).  After reading through a lot of the iOS documentation, I'm pretty sure that it can be done, but was hoping someone who is more familiar could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Shaggy Frog is right, the CGPDF* API does not support PDF modification, including filling form fields.

Comment: While CGPDF doesn't allow direct modification, the end result is what I am looking for.  The approach that I'm thinking of is to open the pdf stream, copy each dictionary item, modify the contents of the form fields, and save into a new pdf.  The part that I need help with though, is ensuring that I copy the entire pdf since the routines that I've looked at allow pulling specific parts out of the pdf instead of giving access to the entire document. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to open a stream and copy it one element at a time to a new file ending up with identical files.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to do with a HTML page. If you wish to use a HTML page instead of a .pdf form then thius is how you would go about doing it:

```
[field1 setText:@"Field 1 Text"];
[field2 setText:@"Field 2 Text"];

NSString *result;
result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('#field1').val('%@');", field1.text]];
result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$('#pfield2').val('%@');", field2.text]];
result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#submitbutton').click();"];
```

You would need to create two UILabels or UITextFields and call them "field2" and "field2" in your .h file. You can then find the ID of the field you need to replace e.g. #field1 and then put it where I have put "#field1" and again for the second field where I have put "#field2". There also needs to be a UIWebView with the page already loaded. This code is to be used **after** the UIWebView page has been loaded. Maybe do the following:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

// Insert above code here

}
```

You probably need a full understanding of Javascript if you want to do this for the whole form, but this should get you started.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the examples, however this does need to be in a pdf!

Comment: Could you not convert the html into a PDF?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an existing, very  complicated pdf that changes regularly so i don't want to recreate (and maintain) it in code (neither as a web page or creating the pdf on the fly).